# Auto Generated/ Predefined Code in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible that every time I create a new file, it generates some default set of code to get started quickly? For example, when I create a C++ file, the main function is already predefined for me.

```cpp
// auto generated ...
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    // Enter your code here.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [File Templates](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.vscode-file-templates) extensions, it also allows snippets and fields